# How do I get the current date in a user's timezone, given an TimeSpan offset?

Tags: c#, date, datetime, .net-core

I need to find what day it is for a user given a Timespan offset.

Right now, this is what I have tried:

```
string timezone = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-MyApp-Timezone"];
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(timezone, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
var consumersCurrentTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, timeSpan);
var consumersCurrentDate = consumersCurrentTime.Date();
```

Which I know doesn't work because `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` takes a `TimeZoneInfo` not a `TimeSpan`. I looked into it a little and found that it's impossible given an offset to get the entire Time Zone information, but I really don't need to know the exact time zone, just what day it is. Is there any way for me to do this?

Comment: maybe this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774124/format-a-date-with-offset) should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string timezone = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-MyApp-Timezone"];
DateTime consumersCurrentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + TimeSpan.Parse(timezone, 
DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
DateTime customersCurrentDate = consumersCurrentDateTime.Date;
```

Comment: What's the difference between using the `+` operator and `ToOffset`? Is one better than the other?

Comment: IMO it's a matter of preference in this case.  Your answer below should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joao Paulo's comment, I think I can do this without involving time zones at all, just by doing this:

```
string timezone = this.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-MyApp-Timezone"];
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(timezone, DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
var consumersCurrentDate = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToOffset(timeSpan).Date;
```